# How to deploy contract in parity-ethereum use json-rpc

Tags: ether, private-blockchain, parity

I'm using atomic swap to exchange money in 2 private blockchain. I used json-rpc to create 2 private chain and created HTLC (Hash time lock contract) to exchange. But I don't know how to deploy contract in private chain. Please help me how to deploy contract in private chain. Can I use remix and metamask to deploy contract?

Comment: It can be done very simply using Remix. Is there any specific issue that you are having in using Remix?

Comment: I used remix to check the contract but i don't know how to connect private chain and deploy it into private chain. I tryed to use parity-ui but i don't solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use remix and metamask to deploy contract?

Yes. You need to do:

1. open MetaMask
2. select network `Custom RPC`
3. fill private chain url (http://1.1.1.1:9545), press Enter
4. import account with positive balance to MetaMask
5. open/refresh Remix (Environment = 'Injected Web3', Account = )
6. write/put contract
7. compile contract with corresponding version of compiler
8. deploy contract

Comment: I used metamask but i used the difference port. I creaed private net as https://wiki.parity.io/Demo-PoA-tutorial. My port is 8540. Therefore, I connected metamask with custom url is http://localhost:8540. Metamask did not activate. I can see my problem by click picture link below:
https://ibb.co/bJwDW9
Do you know my problem?

Comment: The detail of problem is https://ibb.co/ggSvB9

Comment: MetaMask can't connect to node, make sure you that you open rpc port and rpc apis. run curl command to be sure that node is accessible, e.g. `curl --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0x00Bd138aBD70e2F00903268F3Db08f2D25677C9e", "latest"],"id":1}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8540`

Comment: https://ibb.co/bSQS8p
https://ibb.co/fX1Og9
I used to change port from 8540 to 9545. I also restarted chrome and try change url between http://localhost:9545 and http://localhost:9545/
I don't understand why it do not active?

Comment: @phuongvuongnguyen ok, it might help to check the issue https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/5098

Comment: Thank for your ways. I know many ways to solve my problem. I found that i must add cors ="all" in. toml to solve that metamask did not connect with pảity